# math.round decimal number of in sections of 0,2 to 1 decimal

Tags: javascript

I am trying to round up a number into sections of 0.2 (or other variable) in javascript

i have a number 1.34 and what i would like to get out is 1.2

This means the number needs to be rounded down to 1 decimal and split into sections of 0.2(?)

```
math.round((1.34 * 10) / 10) = 1.3
```

but how would i make this into 1.2, it should always round down to the closest 0.2 downwards

Comment: Why `1.2` and not `1.4`. Do you want to get closest value or the value below it? (round or floor)

Comment: @nickzoum it's rounding down.

Comment: @VLAZ In the question it has `round` and not `floor`, that's why I was asking

Comment: it need to round down indeed so 1.2 not 1.4 (perhaps floor indeed)

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the number with the accuracy you want, floor the result and then multiply by the same number.

```js
function round(accuracy, number) {
  if (accuracy <= 0) throw Error("Invalid Accuracy");
  if (accuracy < 1) { // less chance of rounding error
    accuracy = 1 / accuracy;
    return Math.floor(number * accuracy) / accuracy;
  }
  return Math.floor(number / accuracy) * accuracy;
}

var smallRounding = round.bind(null, .2);
var largeRounding = round.bind(null, 5);

console.log("Rounding down to 0.2:");
console.log("1.2 => " + smallRounding(1.2));
console.log("1.25 => " + smallRounding(1.25));
console.log("1.3 => " + smallRounding(1.3));
console.log("1.35 => " + smallRounding(1.35));
console.log("1.4 => " + smallRounding(1.4));

console.log("Rounding down to 5:");
console.log("2 => " + largeRounding(2));
console.log("4 => " + largeRounding(4));
console.log("6 => " + largeRounding(6));
console.log("8 => " + largeRounding(8));
console.log("10 => " + largeRounding(10));
```

Due to the way JavaScript stores fractions it's safer to do `Math.floor(1.25 * (1 / accuracy)) / (1 / accuracy)` than `Math.floor(1.25 / accuracy) * accuracy` when the accuracy is smaller than 1.

```js
console.log(Math.floor(1.25 / 0.2) * 0.2);
console.log(Math.floor(1.25 * (1 / 0.2)) / (1 / 0.2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `Math.floor(x / 0.2) * 0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide by the given slot size and floor the value and multiply this value by the slot.

The result may be not as accurate as wanted, because of the problem of floating point arithmetic.

```js
var value = 1.34,
    slot = 0.2,
    result = (Math.floor(value / slot) * slot).toFixed(2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the result is a string, not a number

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
Number((Math.floor(1.34 / 0.2) * 0.2).toFixed(1))
```